# React project terminates unexpectedly on 'npm start'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app

I ran `npx create-react-app my-app`.  The folder `my-app` was created as expected. In the root folder of the project I ran `npm install` which succeeded, however,  when I ran `npm start` followed by `Starting the development server...` message but immediately exits. There is no error message, and no tab opens in my browser.

**My specs:**

- Windows 10
- node v14.16.0
- npm 7.7.6
- Edge v89.0.774.63 as default browser.

Things I've tried so far and it failed:

- Reinstalling Node.JS (including different versions)
- Running `npm install` and re-trying `npm start` - same result
- Downgrading to npm 6.14.12 - this causes `npm start`to fail with an `ELIFECYCLE` error, as opposed to failing with no error

I am new to React and have no idea how to diagnose this.  I have noticed that `npm start` reports `Project is running at http://<my_IP_address>/` (the IP address is valid for my machine, but it does not include a reference to port 3000, as I expected).  I tried setting the `PORT` environment variable to 3000, but that had no obvious effect.

Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Comment: I've heard `npm 7.7` is breaking a lot of things recently. Try to downgrade to a version one or two patches before the most current release and see?

Comment: I downgraded, same result.

Answer (score 0):

1. npx create-react-app my-app
2. cd my-app
3. npm install
4. npm start

Comment: Thank you.  I failed to mention in my question that I ran "npm install".  I have edited accordingly

Comment: To be clear, re-stating the steps that ought to have worked was not helpful.  The reason for my question is that I followed those steps and did not see the expected result (that is, the development server did not serve my new app, but died instead).